# Improving performance of initializing DbSet in Seed?

Tags: entity-framework, automapper

I am using AutoMapper to map objects from a legacy database to a new database declared in EF code first:

```
  StartTimer("Map Customers");      
      var mfpCustomers = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<LegacyDataModel.Customer>, IEnumerable<Customer>>(
        legacyEntities.Customers.Include(p => p.Demographics).ToList());
      StopAndPrintTimer("Map Customers");

      StartTimer("Iterate Customers");
      foreach (var p in mfpCustomers)
      {
        db.Customers.Add(p);       
      }
      StopAndPrintTimer("Iterate Customers");
```

The for each is what takes the most time.  I would like to map directly to a `DbSet(db.Customer)`, instead of doing a foreach over `db.Customers.Add(p);`.  I haven't figured out how to do this though as there is nothing like an `AddRange` method designed specifically for adding large numbers of objects.  I know how to do these types of transformations with set based techniques in SQL, but that is an insane amount of typing because the intellisense doesn't work that great in those scenarios in SSMS.

This code doesn't need to be super fast, but having to wait a full minute every time I seed the database is making development hard(and it does need to be reseeded often due to rapid development of the new database).  Note also that since this is the seed method, I don't mind completely replacing the existing Customers(since there are none).  So it doesn't need to behave like AddRange in that respect, as I'm really just creating a new collection.

Any ideas on how I can improve the performance here?
Any ideas on how I can map the entire collection directly into the DbSet without doing a foreach on every instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you call db.Customers.Add(p) EF is making a DetectChanges call to see if anything in your entity graph has changed. This helps make things work as expected when Add is called after making changes to other entities. However, DetectChanges can get slow if there are a lot of entities in the context--it has O(n) time on the number of entities. So in cases like you have it can make a big difference if you temporarily turn of these automatic calls to DetectChanges. For example:

```
try
{
    context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

    foreach (var p in mfpCustomers)  
    {  
        db.Customers.Add(p);         
    }  
}
finally
{
    context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
}
```

You can find more details here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/02/06/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-12-automatically-detecting-changes.aspx

Comment: This is great.  It seems to be faster if I call SaveChanges before I set auto detection back to true.  Will it save correctly or any reason to do one before the other?  After implementing this, I noticed something odd where often my initializer wasn't getting called at all, even though I used DropCreateDatabaseAlways.  I actually had to clean and rebuild the project to coerce it into calling my seed function.

Comment: It should save fine in this case if you call SaveChanges before switching DetectChanges back on. If you do any other manipulation of the entities between adding them and calling SaveChanges then it might not save correctly.